# Pass parameter between listview and another page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-listview

I'm trying to make an app in xamarin and till now, after some hour video and many forums I have always find a solution, But this time I'm not able to give it away.

I have a Listview of a list of my own class "Cliente" `private List<Cliente> clienti;`

I have bind the object to the listview to show data and I have put the ItemTapped

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clienti}" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="TapCliente">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,5">
                            <Frame BorderColor="Black">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding rag_sociale}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ind_anag }"/>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding cap_anag }" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding loc_anag }" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding prov_anag }" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Now I would like to open a new page when I tap a row of the list view passing a value of that row to use it in the new page, so I have write:

```
        public void TapCliente(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente cliente_selezionato = (Cliente)
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SchedaAnagraficaPage(cliente_selezionato.cod_anag));
    }
```

The "cod_anag" is an int value, but on the constructor of the new page, I can't set the parameter to receive, If I write:

`public SchedaAnagraficaPage(int codice_cliente)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }`

It write "Can't Convert form views.SchedaAnagraficaPage to Xamarin.Forms.Page"

If I write:

```
        public SchedaAnagraficaPage(Cliente cliente)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

It write "Can't convert from int to models.Cliente"

Any Suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: does `SchedaAnagraficaPage` inherit from `ContentPage`, or some other Page type?

Comment: Maybe **SchedaAnagraficaPage** should using **Xamarin.Forms** and Inherit from **ContentPage**.
So try to do this on your _SchedaAnagraficaPage.xaml.cs_ :
`using Xamarin.Forms;

public partial class SchedaAnagraficaPage : ContentPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , you can check with navigating without paramater whether it works :

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SchedaAnagraficaPage());
```

Then can add `int` argument to navigate .

> Can't Convert form views.SchedaAnagraficaPage to Xamarin.Forms.Page

Occurs this error , need to check the **SchedaAnagraficaPage** whether inherit from ContentPage :

```
public partial class SchedaAnagraficaPage : ContentPage
{

     public SchedaAnagraficaPage(int codice_cliente)
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

In addition ,if write `SchedaAnagraficaPage` method as follow:

```
public SchedaAnagraficaPage(Cliente cliente)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The `TapCliente` method should be as follow :

```
public void TapCliente(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    Cliente cliente_selezionato = (Cliente)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SchedaAnagraficaPage(cliente_selezionato));
}
```